# Saving file from INSERT mode

Tags: insert-mode, save

I would like to save files without exiting the INSERT mode. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use the [`<C-O>`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) keystroke to temporarily leave insert mode for a single command. You can then run `:w<CR>` to write the file and you'll be back to insert mode.

You can use that to create a mapping in insert mode and assign that to a key combination such as `<F3>` or `<C-W>`, using:

```
inoremap <F3> <C-O>:w<CR>
```

Avoid a keystroke such as `<C-S>` ("S" for "Save") since that specific keystroke can be a problem in many terminals or sometimes through remote connections... `<C-S>` is the code for XOFF, which historically has been used to pause a terminal and it's still a valid terminal command in most modern terminals.

If you use a key such as `<F3>`, you might want to also map it in normal mode (without the `<C-O>` in that case) and visual mode, etc. so that it works regardless of which mode you're currently on.

Comment: To disable Ctrl-S hanging the terminal see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72092/2198 . I use Ctrl-S for save as it is great for muscle memory across applications. But if you regularly use new environments that don't share a home directory you'll have to do this fix in each one.